# How can I run a javascript from inside a node.js console?

Tags: node.js

I can run `script.js` from the commandline with `node script.js`.

When I just type `node` I enter the interactive console and see a prompt. How can I execute `script.js` from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `require` it:

```
require('./script')
```

Comment: That works, but I can't access any variables that was defined inside the script.

Comment: I found this answer, that explains module.exports. I can fetch everything I need with that.